# Can't connect to GETH node on the network

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I run a light node on a windows 10 machine on my network with the command:

```
geth --syncmode="light" --cache=4096 -http --http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain "*" -http.api "eth,web3,personal" console
```

The windows 10 machine has the local IP address of 192.168.1.28

When I run a web3 request through the windows machine using the endpoint: `http://localhost:8545` it works perfectly. Once I run the same request on another machine on the network using the endpoint `http://192.168.1.28:8545` the request won't go through.

Any way I can resolve this issue?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geth binds to localhost by default. To allow outside machines to connect, you can add something like this to the parameters:

```
--http.addr "0.0.0.0"
```

See [the Geth documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options) for all possible options.

Comment: Thank you. I am encountering the same issues with web sockets but --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" won't solve it this time. Any remedy?

Comment: Try setting `ws.origins` as well, e.g. `--ws.origins "*"`. Also note that websockets run on port 8546, rather than 8545 by default.